# Installing 'package' as data is deprecated, please list it in `packages` - Package would be ignored

Tags: python, pip

I have been trying to install `crystal-toolkit` and alternatively `crystaltoolkit-extension` but I cannot get through it.

I am on windows, I have tried in the base environment as well as within a conda environment.
I have set up four pip.ini files according to:

```
$ pip config -v list
> For variant 'global', will try loading 'C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini'
> For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\MDI0316\pip\pip.ini'
> For variant 'user', will try loading 'C:\Users\MDI0316\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.ini'
> For variant 'site', will try loading 'c:\programdata\anaconda3\pip.ini'
> global.index-url='https://pypi.python.org/simple/'
> global.proxy='http://uname:pswd@address:port'
> global.timeout='60'
> global.trusted-host='pypi.python.org\npypi.org\nfiles.pythonhosted.org'
> install.index-url='https://pypi.python.org/simple/'
```

And after several attempts, I keep having a `Could not build wheels for crystaltoolkit-extension`
Full error (relevant parts):

```
pip install crystal_toolkit
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Collecting crystal_toolkit
  Using cached crystal_toolkit-2022.6.8-py3-none-any.whl (2.5 MB)
...bunch of stuff...
Collecting crystaltoolkit-extension<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Using cached crystaltoolkit-extension-0.6.0.tar.gz (2.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pymatgen<2023.0.0,>=2022.0.16 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\py38_64\lib\site-packages (from crystal_toolkit) (2022.5.26)
...bunch of stuff...
Building wheels for collected packages: crystaltoolkit-extension
  Building wheel for crystaltoolkit-extension (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for crystaltoolkit-extension (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [119 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running jsdeps
      running handle_files
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib
      creating build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\_version.py -> build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\__init__.py -> build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension
      running egg_info
      writing crystaltoolkit_extension.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to crystaltoolkit_extension.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to crystaltoolkit_extension.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to crystaltoolkit_extension.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'crystaltoolkit_extension.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'jupyter-config\crystaltoolkit-extension.json'
      no previously-included directories found matching '**\node_modules'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'lib'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.ipynb_checkpoints' found anywhere in distribution
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'crystaltoolkit_extension.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      creating build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\package.json -> build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension
      creating build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\474.a2b8326fcfbbe3b6cb15.js -> build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\474.a2b8326fcfbbe3b6cb15.js.LICENSE.txt -> build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\534.e604f16025cd3727f855.js -> build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\568.b028223ccaa16a3bf329.js -> build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\598.d50a9e629232226aaef7.js -> build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\remoteEntry.17e71a0669ae5bd364df.js -> build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\style.js -> build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      installing to build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
      running install
      running install_lib
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit-extension
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension
      copying build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\package.json -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\474.a2b8326fcfbbe3b6cb15.js -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\474.a2b8326fcfbbe3b6cb15.js.LICENSE.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\534.e604f16025cd3727f855.js -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\568.b028223ccaa16a3bf329.js -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\598.d50a9e629232226aaef7.js -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\remoteEntry.17e71a0669ae5bd364df.js -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\style.js -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static
      copying build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\_version.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\crystaltoolkit-extension
      copying build\lib\crystaltoolkit-extension\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\.\crystaltoolkit-extension
      running install_data
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data\data
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data\data\share
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data\data\share\jupyter
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data\data\share\jupyter\labextensions
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data\data\share\jupyter\labextensions\crystaltoolkit-extension
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\package.json -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data\data\share\jupyter\labextensions\crystaltoolkit-extension
      copying install.json -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data\data\share\jupyter\labextensions\crystaltoolkit-extension
      creating build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data\data\share\jupyter\labextensions\crystaltoolkit-extension\static
      copying crystaltoolkit-extension\labextension\static\remoteEntry.17e71a0669ae5bd364df.js -> build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data\data\share\jupyter\labextensions\crystaltoolkit-extension\static
      C:\Users\adm_mwa8552\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l381hlxx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:153: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning:     Installing 'crystaltoolkit-extension.labextension' as data is deprecated, please list it in `packages`.
          !!


          ############################
          # Package would be ignored #
          ############################
          Python recognizes 'crystaltoolkit-extension.labextension' as an importable package,
          but it is not listed in the `packages` configuration of setuptools.

          'crystaltoolkit-extension.labextension' has been automatically added to the distribution only
          because it may contain data files, but this behavior is likely to change
          in future versions of setuptools (and therefore is considered deprecated).

          Please make sure that 'crystaltoolkit-extension.labextension' is included as a package by using
          the `packages` configuration field or the proper discovery methods
          (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
          instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

          You can read more about "package discovery" and "data files" on setuptools
          documentation page.


      !!

        check.warn(importable)
      C:\Users\adm_mwa8552\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-l381hlxx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:153: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning:     Installing 'crystaltoolkit-extension.labextension.static' as data is deprecated, please list it in `packages`.
          !!


          ############################
          # Package would be ignored #
          ############################
          Python recognizes 'crystaltoolkit-extension.labextension.static' as an importable package,
          but it is not listed in the `packages` configuration of setuptools.

          'crystaltoolkit-extension.labextension.static' has been automatically added to the distribution only
          because it may contain data files, but this behavior is likely to change
          in future versions of setuptools (and therefore is considered deprecated).

          Please make sure that 'crystaltoolkit-extension.labextension.static' is included as a package by using
          the `packages` configuration field or the proper discovery methods
          (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
          instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

          You can read more about "package discovery" and "data files" on setuptools
          documentation page.


      !!

        check.warn(importable)
      error: could not create 'build\bdist.win-amd64\wheel\crystaltoolkit_extension-0.6.0.data\data\share\jupyter\labextensions\crystaltoolkit-extension\static\remoteEntry.17e71a0669ae5bd364df.js': No such file or directory
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for crystaltoolkit-extension
Failed to build crystaltoolkit-extension
ERROR: Could not build wheels for crystaltoolkit-extension, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Anyone can help here?
Thanks
Marco

Comment: No solution yet, but I'm in the process of investigating a similar problem with `setup.py install`. This discussion was quite helpful https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5061

Comment: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-could-not-build-wheels-for-which-use-pep-517

see here